# Inserting an image inside a text cell

Tags: image

One can put an evaluated equation inside a text cell, but is it possible to put an imported image in a text cell ? I see nothing in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just try it. I have done it many times. It works fine. In fact you can drag and drop an image from an external document into a text cell.

Here is an example.

[image]

Comment: Somebody sufficiently motivated might want to put a screencast of copy-pasting an image into a text cell...

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, that would be good :-)

Comment: So simple. Often, once the solution is explained, I wonder why I do not think about it myself